# Создаю калькулятор на js. Почему не работаю функции в моем коде?

Tags: javascript

```js
var near=" ";

var value_one,value_two;
var plus,minus,multi,division;

function func1()
{
    var number_one=document.getElementById("but1").value;
    var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=number_one;
    
    
    
    
    if(value_one != undefined)
        {
            value_two=number_one;
        }
    else
        {
            value_one=number_one;
        }
 
}
function func2()
{
    var number_two=document.getElementById("but2").value;
    var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=number_two;
    
  if(value_one != undefined)
        {
            value_two=number_two;
        }
    else
        {
            value_one=number_two;
        }
}
function func3()
{
    var number_three=document.getElementById("but3").value;
    var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=number_three;
    
  if(value_one != undefined)
        {
            value_two=number_three;
        }
    else
        {
            value_one=number_three;
        }
}
function func4()
{
    var number_four=document.getElementById("but4").value;
    var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=number_four;
    
  if(value_one != undefined)
        {
            value_two=number_four;
        }
    else
        {
            value_one=number_four;
        }
}

function plus1()
{
      
    
      var pl=document.getElementById("plus").value;
      var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=pl;
      plus=true;
    
}
function multi()
{

    var ml=document.getElementById("multi").value;
    var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=ml;
    multi=true;
}
function division()
{
    
      var dv=document.getElementById("division").value;
      var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=dv;
    
      division=true;
}
function minus1()
{
      var mn=document.getElementById("minus").value;
      var label=document.getElementById("lb").value=mn;
      minus=true;
}



function result()
{
      var label=document.getElementById("lb");

    
if(plus == true)
    {
    label.value=parseFloat(value_one)+parseFloat(value_two);     
    }
if(minus == true)
    {
         label.value=parseFloat(value_one)-parseFloat(value_two);     
    }
if(multi == true)
    {
         label.value=parseFloat(value_one)*parseFloat(value_two);   
    }
if(division == true)
    {
        label.value=parseFloat(value_one)/parseFloat(value_two);   
    }

    
    
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charsеt=utf-8"> 
<title>Web page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <form>
  <input type="text" id="lb">
      <br/>
            <br/>
      <input type="button" id="but1" value="1"  onclick="func1()">
      <input type="button" id="but2" value="2"  onclick="func2()">
      <input type="button" id="but3" value="3"  onclick="func3()">
      <input type="button" id="but4" value="4"  onclick="func4()">
      <input type="button" id="but5" value="5"  onclick="func5()">
      <input type="button" id="but6" value="6"  onclick="func6()">
      <input type="button" id="but7" value="7"  onclick="func7()">
      <input type="button" id="but8" value="8"  onclick="func8()">
      <input type="button" id="but9" value="9"  onclick="func9()">
      <input type="button" id="but0" value="0"  onclick="func0()">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      
      <input type="button" id="plus" value="+"  onclick="plus1()"  >
      
      <input type="button" id="minus" value="-" onclick="minus1()"  >
      <input type="button" id="multi" value="*" onclick="multi()">
      <input type="button" id="division" value="/" onclick="division()">
       <br/>
      <br/>
       <input type="button" id="equal" value="=" onclick="result()">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на деление и умножение не работают функции  multi() и division(). В чем причина ? Как исправить ?

Comment: Да проблема в одинаковых ID. Поздно, копаться не охота. Тут либо ID-шники элементов перекрывают функции, что менее вероятно. И что более вероятно - указывая имя функции, такое же как ID у элемента, в on* функции, через scope интерпретатор в первую очередь натыкается на сам элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я на **JavaScript** не программировал, но осмелюсь предположить...

У тебя и **переменная** и **идентификатор** и **имя функции** носят одно и то же название...

**multi/ division**

может компилятор (транслятор, чего там у **JS**) запутался.?.

У тебя же **plus** и **plus1**, **minus** и **minus1**...

а **multi** и **division** = **multi** и **division**...

PS допускаю, что компилятор это допускает, но может это ему нужно как то отдельно обговаривать?
А в данном конкретном случае поступить как с плюсом и минусом?

Comment: Вообще, я бы избегал одинаковых названий. Дабы не путаться.